# Is using regular expressions a good idea for check data before insert in database?

Tags: python, regex, database, sqlalchemy

Today i decided to do some exercises to learn `SQLAlchemy` in `Python`.

One idea that came to my mind was to use regular expressions to check all the input before creating a new row in the db.

my model looks like this:

```
class Student(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
matricola = db.Column(db.String(9), nullable=False, unique=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(50))

def __init__(self, matricola, email):
    self.matricola = matricola
    self.email = email


def __repr__(self):
    return "<Studente {}>".format(self.id)
```

so i created this function `createStudent` to insert data in the db:

```
def createStudent(matricola, email):
    matricola_regex = re.compile("(X81|M01)[0-9]{6}")
    email_regex = re.compile("[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@.]+")

    matricola_match = bool(matricola_regex.match(matricola))
    email_match = bool(email_regex.match(email))

    condition = matricola_match and email_match
    if condition:
        new = Student(matricola, email)
        db.session.add(new)
        db.session.commit()
    else:
        print "Error with student data"
```

is this a good way to keep data integrity in the database?

Comment: You may want to consider that it is quite difficult to validate email addresses through regex (or any method other than trying to send an email to the address). See this article for a discussion: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: @blcook thank you i'll check the article. anyway my question is not specific those datas. that's just an example. I'd like to understand if in general it's a good practice to use regex for this purpose.

Comment: You probably want to investigate a forms library like [WTForms](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that will handle validation for you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks daniel. i know about wtforms, but as i mentioned my question is more general. the specific case is just an example.

Comment: Its a good idea in general. You are creating a data layer that validates things before they are placed in the DB. Some people think an ORM like sqlalchemy is evil because it bleeds database implementation into higher level logic. But sqlalchemy does its own flavor of validation. See [Simple Validators](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html) for starts. If you use sqlalchemy, try using its view of validation when possible. That way all users of the model are validated not just those that go through your function.

Comment: @tdelaney thank you! this is the kind of answer i was expecting. 
so in general is it a good idea to have the application handling the data integrity or it is always better to have the database itself handling it? 
what i mean is: is it okay using a solution like mine(with regex) instead of sql CHECK CONSTRAINT? seems to me that if you move the data integrity check to an higher application layer, you have more control over the data.

Comment: Database level constraints have their place - they are limited but apply to inserts where ever they come from. Its not either-or, but as long as you are comfortable that data layer constraints are only good when people call through the constraining code, then there is no problem with them. (IMHO)

Comment: @tdelaney so in my case, i'm good if the only point of access to the db is my function with regex check?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Readers can do what they want, but inserters need the validation. But Do consider the sqlalchemy validators so you need less discipline in your code base.